# Send HTML input to PHP Twilio Script

Tags: php, html, twilio

I'm new to PHP and HTML forms. I'm trying to send the form data below to my PHP script sendsms.php it doesn't seem that the php script is getting the input data from the html form.

```
 <form action="sendsms.php" method="post" >

        <div id="space">Cell:<div><input type="number" name="phone" id="number" ></div></div>
        <div id="space"><div>Message</div><div><input type="text" name="message" id="message">      </div></div>
        <div id="button"><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" id="button" ></div>

    </form>
```

Here is my PHP file sendsms.php

```
<?php

// this line loads the library
require('twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); 

$account_sid = 'REMOEVD'; 
$auth_token = 'REMOVED'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 

$client->account->messages->create(array( 
'To' =>  $_POST['phone'];, 
'From' => "+16194523868", 
'Body' => $_POST['message'];, 

));
```

Comment: you're using `method="post"` but trying to read `$_GET`, you need to use either `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your form:

```
 <form action="sendsms.php" method="post" >
```

you are essentially `post`ing the form inputs, so you need to get the `$_POST` parameters in `PHP` as in :

```
$client->account->messages->create(array( 
    'To' =>  $_POST['phone'], 
    'From' => "+16194523868", 
    'Body' => $_POST['message']
));
```

**Edit**

Just noticed you also have some semicolons (`;`) inside the array declaration which will still break your code

Comment: Dang I knew it was something small like that! Thanks Kypros!